# How does ListPlot3D interpolate data?

Tags: plotting, interpolation, implementation-details

I have data of the form `{{x1, y1, f(x1, y1}, {x2, y2, f(x2, y2)}, ...}`.
I need to interpolate the data to get an interpolated `f(x, y)`.

When I just do `Interpolation[data]`, I get a function, but the result is not very smooth, independent on the interpolation order (there is a difference between the orders, but it does not get better).

When I plot the data with `ListPlot3D[data]`, I get a really nice result. It is really smooth. When I change the interpolation order in `ListPlot3D`, the result does seem to not change, except when going from 0th order to 1st order.

So I would like to get a function, which looks like the result of `ListPlot3D`. How does `ListPlot3D` interpolate the data? Or can I get a function of the `ListPlot3D` result?

#### Edit

First of all, thanks a lot for the detailed answers. I just tried the `InterpolationPolynomial`, but it turned out that it is too demanding for our machine. Maybe, if I post two pictures showing what I'm seeing, one of you will show me how to interpolate my data in the proper way.

First the plot made with `ListPlot3D`, the nice one:

[image]

And the interpolated function plotted:

[image]

My data grid has the resolution of 0.2, so I have 101 x 101 data points; that is, the grid is based on `{x, -10, 10, .2}, {y, -10, 10, .2}`).

As one can clearly see, the second plot shows some edges and is not as smooth as the first one. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: Try `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> All]` - for unstructured grids it may help.

Comment: Could you provide an example data set, or code to generate one?

Comment: Thank you but that does not help.

Comment: This is a question of sampling, not interpolation. `Plot3D` is simply using a coarser mesh than `ListPlot3D`. To get similar results you could tell `Plot3D` to use a similar mesh with the options `PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0`

Comment: Oh my god.......
and i was thinking about that problem for weeks now. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 3):

**Quality of Interpolation**

I don't have any insight into the interpolation scheme of *Mathematica*, but I can describe how I would interpolate toward the best approximation.

*Mathematica* has a whole battery of numerical interpolation functionality. But how to achieve the same quality, as the specific plot do?

One interpolation function that comes to my mind here is *InterpolatingPolynomial*.

Let's take a function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x / 2)^2$ and interpolate it in the interval $\{-1, 1\}$.

```
n = 50;
f[x_] := Sin[Pi x/2]^2;
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1, 2/n}];
```

Now let's do some interpolation with data:

```
ipo[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[data // N, x];
```

And compare the original function with the interpolated polynomial:

```
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{
    Plot[#, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
        DisplayFunction -> Identity]& /@ {f[x], ipo[x]}
}}]]
```

[image]

In order to qualify the interpolation there is a quantification step, to determine the error as a function of n. With this it is possible to determine the best approximation in some interval.

The above function is a smooth function on the specific interval, but what if we have to interpolate a function with a specific singularity near some interval?

If this is the case we have to deal with the so called [Runge phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

Let's take for instance the function as defined in the above article on Wikipedia:

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 25 x^2);
```

If we re-evaluate everything we get this plot:

[image]

Here the interpolation oscillates toward the end of the interval. If something like this happens it is best to use nonequidistant x-values. On that specific case the best asymptotic density is given by the formula:

$1/\sqrt{(1 - x^2)}$

These nodes are known as *[Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes)*

So what we see here is, that the specific plot functions work roughly in two steps:

1. Create an Interpolation function
2. Qualify the Interpolation function through quantification

I have to leave now, but try to come back to your interesting question again and get more into the specifics; how I think *Mathematica* does the interpolation or how I'd do it if I were *Mathematica* (that's not the case, which is good luck for *Mathematica*).

Comment: Near a single point, Taylor series is clearly superior, but expanding in terms of Chebyshev polynomials gives a better global bound. So, the phrase "best approximation" is dependent on your goal.

Comment: @rcollyer yes you're absolutely right. i guess the best approximation is from the plot itself and i was tempted to write something about getting a plot and extract the interpolated data from there....but then the issue changed and simon gave an answer the OP was actually searching for. But I have to say, by means of defending myself. The original question, as I understood, was about how ListPlot3D does the interpolation...now it became a more practical one.

Comment: but maybe I just understood the question wrong, which wouldn't be the first ... sigh

Comment: not likely. I was just nit-picking on nomenclature.

Comment: Understood :) jokester

Answer (score 3):

I will answer the question posed in the title:

> How does `ListPlot3D` interpolate data?

It uses a Delaunay triangulation of the projection of the points on the $xy$ plane. This is essentially the same as using first-order `Interpolation` (which at present is the only interpolation scheme available for unstructured data). Observe:

```
SeedRandom[0];
points = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];

ListPlot3D[points, NormalsFunction -> None]
```

[image]

```
f = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Compare the top view of the mesh used by `ListPlot3D` to the Delaunay triangulation of just the $xy$ coordinates:

```
ListPlot3D[points, Mesh -> All, NormalsFunction -> None, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

```
DelaunayMesh[Most /@ points]
```

[image]